# Access same function with different routing prefix in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to access below function with different routing prefixes without rewriting it again:

```
public function togglePermission() {
  //code goes here
}
```

1) I know below will serve purpose for admin

```
public function admin_togglePermission() {
  //code goes here
}
```

2) and this one for manager

```
public function manager_togglePermission() {
  //code goes here
}
```

Comment: You can put `togglePermission()` in `AppController` and for example in `admin_togglePermission()` referer by `parent::togglePermission()`

Answer (score 0):

Like kicaj is saying, if you're trying to access a single function from multiple models you can create that function inside of the appController.php.

```
//appController.php
Private function thisFunction (){
//stuff and thing
}
```

Then call that function from other controllers

```
//any other controller
$this-> thisFunction();
```